# Split a layer using polygons from another layer

Tags: qgis, clip

I have a landuse layer that I would like to separate into different administrative units. What is the fastest way to achieve this in QGIS?

[image: Land use layer] 
[image: admin units]

Comment: Do you have a the administrative units as polygons? Are they perchance in a shapefile? Are you trying to do this in python or interactively? If in python how far have you got? How many unique administrative units do you have?

Comment: Do you have the land use data in raster or vector format?

Comment: Both layers are polygon shapefiles. The admin units layer has got 36 polygons. I wish to do it interactively.

Comment: Please help us with a little more information and maybe a screenshot?What do you want the result to be?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create separate layers with landuse for each administrative unit, you can use **Clip vectors by polygon** or **Clip** from processing toolbox (or from QGIS 2.16 also in menu *Vector -> Geoprocessing tools -> Clip*) and enable *iterate over this layer* (green arrow button [image]) option on administrative units layer. This cause that clip runs on landuse with each feature (polygon) from administrative layer separately.

[image]

If you want to create new layer with both layers overlapping in one, use **Union** instead of clip.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that iterate icon before, thank you. This approach would also work if the landuse layer was a raster (by using **Clip raster by mask layer** instead)

Comment: @StevenKay sure :), I didn't mention it because OP has shapfile layer. Iteration is nice feature, its available almost in all functions with vector layer input. Only thing I miss is some built-in output renaming, in case of vectors I can handle it with python scritpting, but for rasters its complicated (for me :) ).

Comment: @ Oto thanks. Using the iterator worked. However, most shapefiles were empty. what could be the problem?